# Why is _text address in Linux ARM64 boot so high?

Tags: linux-kernel, boot, arm64

I'm currently learning about ARM64 architecture, and I have trouble understanding how Linux can boot. From the linker script, we can see that:

```
  SECTIONS {
    . = PAGE_OFFSET + TEXT_OFFSET;

    .head.text : {
        _text = .;
        HEAD_TEXT
    }
```

the initial `_text` symbol is very high, something like `0xfffffffc000080000`. To my knowledge, this address is a *physical* address, but this seems impossible on a 8Gb RAM based board. How is this possible ? Am I missing something ?

EDIT: The [Linux documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/arm64/booting.txt) states that:

```
- Caches, MMUs
  The MMU must be off.
```

Comment: _"Am I missing something?"_ - yes. It's not a physical address (that would be `PHYS_OFFSET`).

Comment: But Linux requests to boot with MMU off, or maybe that's no longer the case ?

Comment: Sure, and the tiny bit of entry point code which runs with the MMU off doesn't use virtual addresses (directly). That doesn't affect the fact that vmlinux is linked to run from the final linear map address range (in TTBR1), and thus the premise of the question is invalid.

Comment: Ok so you say that the whole kernel is linked with high addresses, but the early boot code, is position independent and so don't bother about its real location. Did I understand right ?

Comment: It's somewhat of a simplification, but pretty much, yes. By the time you get as far as C code you're running from proper virtual addresses, it's just that _a lot_ happens from one end of head.S to the other (which I won't even claim to fully understand).

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. Don't hesitate to put some of that knowledge in an answer (even a partial one) so I can properly clause the thread ;)